# Test raspberry power supply

Tags: power, pi-3b+

I have a raspberry pi 3 B+ and an external hdd [like this one](https://www.bgrsolutions.net/product/seagate-1tb-external-hard-drive/)

Connecting it directly to the pi makes the pi shutdown and restart

I’ve tried to use an external usb hub with power but it still keeps resetting

How can I test if the problems is with the raspberry?

---

**EDIT**

For the requested informations:

```
HUB + PC => Works
HUB on Power (5v 1A) + PC => Works

Raspberry on Power (5v 2A) => Works (some freezes over ssh but I think because of network)
Raspberry on Power (5v 2A) + HUB and HDD on Power (5v 1A) => RPi keeps reseting
Raspberry and HUB and HDD on the original *HUB Power* (5v 1A) => RPi keeps reseting

Raspberry + HDD on Power (5v 2A) => Kinda works (a lot of freezes over ssh the power led shuts down for long periods, 1s-3s)
```

I know that placing all devices on the original HUB power supply will not work (because it is rated at 1A) but I've tried using two PSU, one for the hub and other for the pi, but it still keeps resetting

I think the hub is not properly powering the HDD and the pi is trying fill the gap

---

**EDIT 2** Added pictures

This works, kinda:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDIM2.jpg

These doesn't work:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcFsc.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mose7.jpg

Album: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWii1.jpg

Comment: Does the Pi work if the external drive is not connected?  No - the Pi is bad, Yes - the Pi is okay.

Comment: Then why the external powered hub did not work? Shouldn’t it had worked?

Comment: I have no idea.  Perhaps you should add details your question and show exactly what did not work (with photos if possible).

Comment: @joan   The OP should post the Amperage rating of his power supply and whether the pi works correctly without the HDD + hub

Answer (score 1):

Test the combination of PC+hub+HDD.  If you can transfer large files to and from the PC,<=HUB=> HDD, then you can isolate the problem to the Pi and its power supply.  Ensure the rPI has its own power supply and meets the minimum requirement (most likely problem).   Try powering the rPi with your iPhone's or iPad power supply.

If you still have problems, then it is likely that the initial current spike to start the drive is drawing more current than the hub can provide.  I this case you would need a hub that could source enough current to spin up (transient current) the drive to a steady state.

Comment: I've added the scenarios I've tested, can you take a look?

Comment: I do not see an test result for:  PC+hub+HDD.    Verify that you can copy a large file to and from the PC and HDD.  Does the rPi have its own power supply: if yes what is the supply's current (Amperage rating), which powers the rPi?

Comment: `PC+HUB+HDD` does work, like I've said in the first edit. Even `PC+HDD` works just fine.

Comment: If 'PC+HUB+HDD' works correctly, then the problem is within 'rPi+PS', where PS is power supply.  Try powering with supply rated at least 1.5 A.

Comment: Like this: https://i.imgur.com/1sN3Ita.jpg ? The white PS is rated at 2A and it still doesn't work

Comment: I can not read the rating on the power supply, so I will take your word that it is 2A.  I added a comment regarding the transient current demand from the Hub.  You would be better off using a HDD that has its own power supply: keep it simple.  I realize that this is not what you want to hear, however, this is IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Test your system with my "rpiburn" program. It is designed specifically for power supply testing:
https://github.com/ronny-nilsson/rpiburn